# Powershell - transform fully qualified paths into PS drive-based paths using string replacement

Tags: powershell, replace, path, registry

I have this code which finds a registry key with the name "c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e". This works perfectly. However the variable also has Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office..path to found key in when it completes. How do I remove the Microsoft.powershell.core\Registry:: part?

```
$path = ls 'HKCU:\' -Recurse | where { $_.Name -like 
 '*c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e*' } | Select PSParentPath | ft -AutoSize -Wrap
```

I looked at using the .replace function on a variable like below:

```
$path.replace ("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "HKU:")
```

I get this error:  `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData] does not contain a method named 'replace'.`. But If I do this on a normal variable, the `.replace` part works fine

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Formatting cmdlets such as `ft`** (`Format-Table`) are only ever **meant for  *displaying* data** - **do not use their output as *data* for *subsequent processing***.

  - Remove `| ft -AutoSize -Wrap` from your first command.
  - Because `ft` produces output objects of types such as `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData]`, which have no `.Replace()` method, your call failed.
- You were looking for the `[string]`-type `.Replace()` method, but even without the `ft` call, **`Select PSParentPath` doesn't output *strings*, but *wrapper objects* that have a `.PSParentPath` *property*** with the desired values. To output the values only, use `-ExpandProperty`:

  - Use `Select -ExpandProperty PSParentPath` to skip the wrapper object and output the `.PSParentPath` values directly, as *strings*.

To put it all together (using `Get-ChildItem` instead of alias `ls`, and `Where-Object` instead of alias `where`):

```
$path = Get-ChildItem HKCU:\ -Recurse | Where-Object {
  $_.Name -like '*c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e*' 
} | Select -ExpandProperty PSParentPath

$path.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "HKCU:")
```

---

Here's a **streamlined alternative solution** that:

- assumes that it is sufficient to apply the wildcard pattern to the registry key *names* only (the `.Name` property actually reports the full key *path*), in which case `Get-ChildItem`'s `-Include` parameter can be used.
- uses PowerShell's `-replace` *operator*, which - unlike the `.Replace()` string *method*, operates on *regular expressions*, which enables many more features; in the case a hand, it allows anchoring the match at the start of the string `^` (but conversely requires escaping regex metachars. such as `.` and `\` with `\`).

```
(Get-ChildItem HKCU:\ -Recurse -Include *c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e*)
 .PSParentPath -replace '^Microsoft\.PowerShell\.Core\\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER', 'HKCU:'
```